# Меняем задний фон для slick-slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Просмотрел весь slick-slider нашел пару функций типа afterChange и beforeChange но не могу разобраться, суть вопроса в том что есть слайдер с фотками людей так вот надо передавать фотку на задний фон соседнего элемента при прокрутке. то есть у нас есть

```
<div class="slide__inner box-team slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 1140px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide02">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 wrapper-box-image">
                        <div class="box-image" style="background: url({img}от сюда будем брать фото) no-repeat center center/cover"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet culpa dolores dolorum in labore nisi optio ratione tempore velit voluptates! Commodi eos et, inventore ipsa iusto necessitatibus officia placeat voluptatem.
                        </div>
                    </div></div><div id="team_text" style="{img}тут должна быть картинка"></div>
```

В общем такая идея, не нашел варианта как сделать выборку картинки и продублировать ее в блок, кто может подсказать.И логика в том что данный элемент не является частью slicka он вообще далеко вне него.

Пока смог только додумать до такого

```
$('.slick-slider-gallery').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
            var img_bg = $(".box-image").attr("style");
            $("#team_text").attr("style", img_bg);
    });
```

Но не могу теперь придумать как повесить событие на слайдер что бы при нажатии на next или prev менялся bacground в принципе он все переносит.

Comment: Параметр Slider Syncing не подходит? Управление из одного слайдера другим слайдером

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос таким способом.

```
$('.slick-slider-gallery').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
            var img_bg = $('.box-team:eq('+ (nextSlide+1) +')').find(".box-image").attr("style");
            console.log(img_bg, $("#team-text").length);
            $("#team-text").attr("style", img_bg);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="header_slider">
    <div className="item_slider_top" data-text1="/img/f.jpg">
        Слайд
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.header_slider').on('beforeChange', function(){
        var img_bg = $('.item_slider_top.slick-current').data( "text1" );
        $('.top_banner').css({'background-image' : 'url('+img_bg+')'});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]